# the limit of a sequence with a 3rd root

Tags: calculus, limits

I am an bachelor degree level constructional engineer and I have a problem solving a sequence with a 3rd root (I believe is the correct term). My degree lacks the mathematical education to find a general solution for the Nth term in this kind of sequence, so I could use some help. Furthermore, English is not my native tongue, so excuse my language.

If you are not interested in the background, you can skip to the bottom where the problem with the seqeunce is adressed.

The problem is about dimensioning a concrete beam, based on the deflection of the beam. The following formula for the height is obtained :

$$[1]h=\sqrt[3]{\frac{60ql^{3}}{1,536Eb}}$$

where q is the load in $N/_{mm^{2}}$, l is the length of the beam in mm, E is the tensile modules in $N/_{mm^{2}}$ and b is the width in mm.

In my specific case l=10000, E=10000, b=1000 and q=5, this will obtain a height h1 of 269 mm.

Ofcourse the weight of the beam creates an extra load of hx0,025. To account for this we need to calculate again with a new value for q : q=5+0,025h= 5+0,025*269=11,725.

This will obtain a height of 358 mm. I have computed this in excel and iteration shows it diverges to 385 mm.

Now for a more general view l,E and b are all constant and so [1] can be rewriten as.

$$[2]h=\sqrt[3]{cq}$$

now for h1, q=5, we get :

$$h_1=\sqrt[3]{c5}$$

now for h2, to the load q, the weight of the beam h1 is added : q=5+0,025xh1 so the formula for h2 becomes :

$$h_2=\sqrt[3]{c(5+0,025h_1)}$$

now we repeat and we get :

$$h_3=\sqrt[3]{c(5+0,025h_2)}$$

***A repeating pattern is observed of the following sequence :***

$$[3]h_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{c(5+0,025h_n)}$$

***Now a I have a problem finding a function for the nth term.***

The reason why I am seeking this function, is to calculate the limit analytically, which I find more sattisfying then numerically with excel.

Furthermore and more important, I wonder if it is possible to obtain a formula where q is inserted and the needed height h is given, where the height h is also taken into consideration for its extra load. So basically no iteration needed.
I dont know if such a thing is analytically possible.

But it would be very cool and usefull, because the term E is an estimate that is also dependant on the variable height and load en thus deflection. So solving this problem could help me along the way to finding a formule where E is given to.

So the whole dimensioning of a beam is very iteration heavy, which is easy but also very repetative and feels kinda amateurish to me. Which in itself is no problem, I just think it is worth the effort to put some work in to automating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iteration is a fixed point iteration $h_{n+1}=f(h_n)$. Under suitable circumstances it converges to the fixed point of the fixed-point equation $h=f(h)$. Often it is faster to solve this or an equivalent equation by other means like the Newton method.

---

Your fixed-point equation is $h=\sqrt[3]{c(5+0.025·h)}$.

By taking the third power you get the cubic equation
$$
h^3=c(5+0.025·h)
$$
which has exactly one positive real solution.

---

Now one could use the Cardano formula for a completely analytical solution formula. However, this method becomes numerically unstable for large coefficients like the ones in this problem.

---

Using Newtons method to solve this cubic equation should give faster convergence.
$$
h_{n+1}=h_n-\frac{h_n^3-c·(q+0.025·h_n)}{3h_n^2-c·0.025}
$$

Comment: First off thank you for your response. I do not really understand your answer. I am trying to find the function for the Nth term of the sequence [3]. When c=3906250, iteration shows this series converges to 385. Solving the equation for c=3906250, gives h=159 (aproximate). So I am not trying to solve the equation h^3=c(5+0.025xh), also i dont really know what this value means. furthermore I do not think [3] is the same as h^3=c(5+0.025h) because in the latter, the h's are the same variables but in [3] hn+1 =/= hn

Comment: That is not possible, the numerical iteration is the best you get. Your iteration is a fixed point iteration $h_{n+1}=f(h_n)$. Under suitable circumstances it converges to the fixed point of the fixed-point equation $h=f(h)$. Often it is faster to solve this or an equivalent equation by other means like the Newton method.